# For each delegated item in FolderListModel do

Tags: qt, qml

I have a QML app that I currently lists files in a directory. I now want to add a way to run a function for each delegates item eg. for each file in the set dir.
Or really each file through a function (adding them to a local db)

How do I do that using QML?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `Component.onCompleted` 
However this may be called multiple times, so i wouldn't recommend you update databases using this.
(I hope you have a plugin to update the DB.)

```
import QtQuick 1.0
import Qt.labs.folderlistmodel 1.0

ListView {
    width: 200; height: 400

    FolderListModel {
        id: folderModel
        nameFilters: ["*.qml"]
    }

    Component {
        id: fileDelegate
        Text {
            text: fileName
            Component.onCompleted: {
                //DO WHATEVER YOU WANT HERE
                console.log("process the file"+fileName);
            }
        }
    }

    model: folderModel
    delegate: fileDelegate
}
```

Original code taken from http://doc.qt.digia.com/4.7/src-imports-folderlistmodel.html and modified to suit the answer

Comment: Thank you, that did indeed help. The thing is, though, that it doesn't load all of the items at once, When I'm scrolling trough the list, more items gets loaded progressively, and scrolling up again prints out items that's already been handled. Just like you mention. But I Want all the items to be run trough a function once.

How?

Comment: @DanielHolm : ListView has dynamic loading. If you want to manage loading yourself, use Repeater instead.